# string in an array not appearing as entered

Tags: vba, excel

So i am trying to create a simple string, the code is pretty simple

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim yr As Variant
Dim site As Variant
  yr = Array("2013", "2014")
  site = Array("SHR", "SHW", "SHH")
  q = 0
  a = 0

  Range("D3").Formula = "\\shared\Export\STA30\" & site(q) & "\" & Year(a) & "\XL\"

End Sub
```

pretty basic, and it works, but the output is:

```
\\shared\Export\STA30\SHR\1899\XL\
```

I'm presuming something has happened to my excel settings? I have used arrays like this in the past and have never encountered this problem. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: perhaps you wanted to use `yr(a)` rather than `Year(a)`? [Year() is a reserved word for a VBA function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg264675(v=office.14).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use yr(a) insted of Year(a).
Year(int) return the converted int into year.

Comment: @AlexDobbin Rudeness is not tolerated here.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared an array as yr and when you are printing in the output string you are using year(a).

Just change the year(a) to yr(a) and you would get the desired output.